# Settings keys to Azure Key Vault for sub-levels

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, connection-string, azure-keyvault, appsettings

For user secret management, I use user secrets for the development stage and I want to use Azure key vault for release and staging.
I have this configuration

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "MySecretConnectionString"
},
"SmtpSettings": {
  "SmtpMailServer": "smtp.mailserver.somewhere",
  "SmtpPort": "465",
  "SenderLogin": "login",
  "SenderDisplayName": "Site ",
  "SenderPassword": "password",
  "SenderEmail": "site@mailserver.somewhere",
  "SecureSocketSettings": "SslOnConnect"
}
```

Problem arises when i want to set `ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection` or `SmtpSettings:SenderPassword` in in Azure key vault.

*Is there any way to assign and use value to nested properties?* For example like I do for user-secrets with

```
dotnet user-secrets set "SmtpSettings:SenderPassword" "########" --project MyProject
```

but for Azure key vault

```
az keyvault secret set --name "SmtpSettings:SenderPassword" --value "######" --vault-name MyProjectVault
```

: is not allowed, `Parameter 'secret_name' must conform to the following pattern: '^[0-9a-zA-Z-]+$'.`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use `--` as it stated in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#secret-storage-in-the-production-environment-with-azure-key-vault)

> Azure Key Vault secret names are limited to alphanumeric characters
> and dashes. Hierarchical values (configuration sections) use -- (two
> dashes) as a delimiter, as colons aren't allowed in key vault secret
> names. Colons delimit a section from a subkey in ASP.NET Core
> configuration. The two-dash sequence is replaced with a colon when the
> secrets are loaded into the app's configuration.

```
az keyvault secret set --name "SmtpSettings--SenderPassword" --value "######" --vault-name MyProjectVault
```